how to open 3389 TCP on CSF for Remote Desktop Connection in CentOS 7?
Recently I installed CSF and disabled firewalld on centos 7
when it was on firewalld there was no problem with remote connection
but now I'm not able to connect throught remote desktop because of CSF firewall.
I added ,3389 to TCP_IN TCP_OUT TCP6_IN TCP6_OUT in CSF firewall configuration and restart CSF but connection is not okay via RDP.
I'm just able to connect using RDP When I stop csf using systemctl stop csf.
Any help to find a way to solve this problem please.

Sorry but I solved the problem so fast :D
I was using to restart csf and affect changes
systemctl restart csf
but there is another way to restart csf currectly and that is
csf -r
